# Define abstract class with abstract methods in pattern design style

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstract-methods

How to define abstract methods in abstract class using design patterns while some methods of methods would be possible to *override* or change it's behavior in child classes?
In this example, `public abstract class GameCharacter` have method `attack` which should be pattern like (define some of the methods in `GameCharacter` and some leave empty, to be * overridden* in child classes).

```
public abstract class GameCharacter{

public void attack(GameCharacter opponent){

while(opponent.hitPoints > 0 && this.hitPoints > 0){

// some abstract method which behavior can be *redefined* 
//if specific class is *overrides* 
// some of this functions
// it should be pattern design

public void doDamageToOpponent{ 

doAttackOne(){ .... }; // cannot change
doAttackTwo(); // can change, be overridden in child class

}

public void doDamageToThis{ // counterattack

doAttackOne(){ .... }; // cannot change
doAttackTwo(); // can change, be overriden in child class

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is something like this:

```
public abstract class GameCharacter{

    protected abstract doAttackTwo();

    protected final doAttackOne() { ... implement here ... }

    ...
}
```

`doAttackTwo()` must be implemented by the subclasses, whereas `doAttackOne()` cannot be overridden.

Comment: Why *protected abstract doAttackTwo();* is protected?

Comment: `protected` means, that only this class `GameCharacter` and alls of its subclasses can access the method, so it is "protected" from access from other points in your code. If you do not want this, you can declare them as `public`; in that case you can call both methods from every point in your code. In general it can be wise to only allow access to members if you really need to have it, so I used `protected` instead of `public`.

Comment: Protected can also be accessed from any classes in the same package, even if they are not a subclass of GameCharacter.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I always forget this one. I still feel like there should be an access modifier that allows exclusion of package access - well, except `private` of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a method as `final` it cannot be overriden in a subclass. And of course, if you don't give a method a definition any (concrete) subclass must implement it.